# How does API authentication works with only public key on javascript?

Tags: javascript, api, public-key

English is not my first language. I'll do my best to explain my self.

---

I am creating an API to be used by clients via Javascript. The client should include on his website something like this:

```
<script>
    var my_api = { 
        public_key: "123456"
    };
</script>
<script async src="https://api.example.com/v1/init.js"></script>
```

So... how can I use a Public Key to verify the client's website?

I know I can get the referer and compare it in with the key on my database, but:

(a) If the referer may be faked, a public key won't be useful because is already public

And (b) if the referer can't be faked, Why would I use a public key? Is not enougth with the referer?

I can't ask the client to encrypt something to varify if he have the right key if anybody can knows the key...

I have only created APIs with both private and public key (or only private) in the past.

Finally, I want it all be installed on client's website by copy/pasting few lines of JS code (that's why I want only use public key).

I know it is possible because that's how Google Ads works, I just need help to figure out the way.

---

Note: I searched for other topic on the forum but I couldn't find any answer, just thing related the SSH and nodeJS. I am developing a simple API with PHP and pure JS.

Comment: This is why APIs that require keys are not usually used directly from the client, they have to be used from the server.

Comment: Yes, I know. I've developed server side APIs before. But Google Ads, Maps and other famous services works this way, so, I am not sure what to think about.

Comment: If they do, they're not worried about someone using someone else's credentials.

Comment: Probably... maybe I have to consider if this could be an approach. I guess this is an option if you ar not showing sensitive data or they have not too pay based on the number of request.

Comment: A good example is the Stripe API. Each vendor gets two keys, a public key and a hidden key. The public key is used in the client to translate the credit card input to a temporary Stripe token. The private key is used on the server to submit the order. Nothing sensitive can be accessed with the public key.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you might run into with putting the api key on their website is that it could be viewed by anyone and used. Use a `Process` environment variable on the system they are using to host their site. You can use this resource for information: https://hackernoon.com/how-to-use-environment-variables-keep-your-secret-keys-safe-secure-8b1a7877d69c

Comment: Can't they just modify the JS and use somtehing like `console.log(ENV.myApiKey);` to see the key?

Comment: You cannot use `console.log` (from the DOM) on a environment variable that is set on the backend. 

DOM javascript != Node.js

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "modify the JS"? Like type into a console on the browser? People who have access to the non-execute-ready javascript will definitely have access to be able to find the api key.

Comment: Ok... well, with the new link on your update, I can understand better what enviroment variables are. But, sadly, this looks to Node.js and I can't force all my clients to use nodeJS. I need plain Javascript, like Google Ads or Google Maps.

Comment: This answer seems to be talking about server-side technology. The question is about doing the API call from the client.

Comment: In that case, just go with your original solution of just storing it in a variable. 
`var pleaseStealThisKeyAndDoWhateverYouWantWithIt = 'my-super-secret-code1234';`